# ASUS USB Crosslink cable filesharing

Tags: usb

I've purchased Asus USB Crosslink cable 2GB. I've read this answer:https://superuser.com/a/335822/108197

and I was hoping I could achieve similar behavior.

But after i connect two linux boxes together I get:
flash drive on (one machine), CD-ROM with some windows software(both machines), some writable but not persistent filesystem(both machines).

I cannot fileshare, sync or flashshare as is written on the box.

Anyone have any experince with this device.

Thanks in advance